# How to convert tensorflow image Tensor to Numpy array inside Dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, opencv

I want to create some image mask during image augmentation.
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMEaA.jpg)

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import pandas

# You can replace to local image
train_df = pd.DataFrame({'image_id': ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMEaA.jpg'],  
                         'label': [1]})


def create_mask(image, label):
    print(type(image)) # <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
    if isinstance(image, str):
        img = cv2.imread(image)
    else:
        img = image

    ## convert to hsv
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    ## mask of green (36,0,0) ~ (70, 255,255)
    mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 0, 0), (70, 255,255))
    ## mask o yellow (15,0,0) ~ (36, 255, 255)
    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, (15,0,0), (36, 255, 255))
    ## final mask and masked
    mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask1, mask2)
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask=mask)
    return result, label

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    train_df.image_id.values,train_df.label.values))
train_ds = train_ds.map(create_mask)
```

As result I get error because we have a tensor in the "image":

***hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)***

**TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'**

Ok, we need a numpy array. But if I try
img = image.numpy()
I got error:

**AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'**
As expected...

Also I tried eval() with sess.run() but got error for placeholder, something like "tensor unhashable, use tensor.ref()", but if I use ref(), I get something like "cannot use Tensor".

Well, I have one simple question - can anybody advice me a working way to convert Tensor to numpy array during image process  inside tf.data.Dataset?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. I need to convert to numpy to use Albumentations. Were you able to find a way?

Answer (score 0):

Try using only Tensorflow functions. For example, you can use [`tf.image.rgb_to_hsv`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/rgb_to_hsv).

```
rgb = tfio.experimental.color.bgr_to_rgb(img)
hsv = tf.image.rgb_to_hsv(rgb)
```

You should find a Tensorflow way to do the following operations too.